# Python Basics - comparison, indents, if ... else

Tags: python-2.7

The code should accept arguement from command-line and print "bad input" if 'a' is greater than 5 and "good input" if not. or at least that is what i want it to do. Could someone please explain why this is not working as expected ? (P.S - this is my first python code ever)

```
 import sys

 def main():
        print sys.argv[1]
        ##print len(sys.argv[1])
        a=sys.argv[1]
            if a > 5:
                print "bad input"
            else:
                print "good input"


 if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC1uX.png)

Comment: The elements of `sys.argv` are strings, and comparing strings to integers is not meaningful.  You need to use `int()` to convert the user-supplied string to an integer.

Comment: Hey jason , i changed it to a=int(sys.argv[1]) . and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just need to fix your indents and it works fine.

```
import sys

def main():
    a = sys.argv[1]
    if a > 5:
        print "bad input"
    else:
        print "good input"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: that didnt work mate. a=int(sys.argv[1]) made it work. but thanks anyways

Comment: Really? running `python script.py 10` didn't print `bad input`? Which python version are you using?

Comment: version python27

Answer (score 0):

The arguments that you get from command line are in **string** format, so before you can do any mathematical operation you must convert it to integer like here **a = int(sys.argv[1])** And don't start next line with spacing, that's not needed. Solution below:

```
import sys

def main():

    print(sys.argv[1])

    a = int(sys.argv[1])

    if a > 5:
        print ("bad input")
    else:
        print ("good input")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```